# coredns pod is not running in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I install kubernetes 1000 times but now it does not work.
I install kubectl kubeadm kubelet then

```
 sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=185.73.114.92
 kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

but I see coredns is in pending state

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-5644d7b6d9-492q4          0/1     Pending   0          13m
kube-system   coredns-5644d7b6d9-cvwjg          0/1     Pending   0          13m
kube-system   etcd-amghezi                      1/1     Running   0          12m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-amghezi            1/1     Running   0          12m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-amghezi   1/1     Running   0          12m
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-fkxnf       1/1     Running   0          12m
kube-system   kube-proxy-pspw2                  1/1     Running   0          13m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-amghezi            1/1     Running   0          12m
```

and then I get describe of coredns

```
kubectl describe pods coredns-5644d7b6d9-492q4 -n kube-system
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
  ----     ------            ----       ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

I taint the node by

```
kubectl taint nodes amghezi node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

It did not work
I see at

```
journalctl -xe
message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized

service docker status
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-09-22 17:29:45 CEST; 34min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 987 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 20
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─987 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Sep 22 17:29:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 22 17:29:45 ubuntu dockerd[987]: time="2019-09-22T17:29:45.728818467+02:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Sep 22 17:29:45 ubuntu dockerd[987]: time="2019-09-22T17:29:45.757401709+02:00" level=warning msg="failed to retrieve runc version: unknown output format: runc version spec: 1.0.1-dev\n"
Sep 22 17:29:45 ubuntu dockerd[987]: time="2019-09-22T17:29:45.786776798+02:00" level=warning msg="failed to retrieve runc version: unknown output format: runc version spec: 1.0.1-dev\n"
Sep 22 17:29:46 ubuntu dockerd[987]: time="2019-09-22T17:29:46.296798944+02:00" level=warning msg="failed to retrieve runc version: unknown output format: runc version spec: 1.0.1-dev\n"
Sep 22 17:29:46 ubuntu dockerd[987]: time="2019-09-22T17:29:46.364459982+02:00" level=warning msg="failed to retrieve runc version: unknown output format: runc version spec: 1.0.1-dev\n"
Sep 22 17:30:06 ubuntu dockerd[987]: time="2019-09-22T17:30:06.996299645+02:00" level=warning msg="failed to retrieve runc version: unknown output format: runc version spec: 1.0.1-dev\n"
Sep 22 17:30:41 ubuntu dockerd[987]: time="2019-09-22T17:30:41.633452599+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Sep 22 17:30:41 ubuntu dockerd[987]: time="2019-09-22T17:30:41.633831003+02:00" level=warning msg="d72e19bd0e929513a1c9092ec487e5dc3f3e009bdaa4d33668b610e86cdadf9e cleanup: failed to unmount IPC: umount /var/lib/docker/containers/d72e19bd0e929513a1c9092ec487e5dc3f3e009bdaa4d33668b610e86cdadf9e/mounts/shm, flags: 0x2
Sep 22 17:30:41 ubuntu dockerd[987]: time="2019-09-22T17:30:41.903058543+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities,or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap."
```

and let us see kubelet status

```
Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

Comment: What's the output of `kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.taints}"`

Comment: map[effect:NoSchedule key:node-role.kubernetes.io/master] map[effect:NoSchedule key:node.kubernetes.io/not-ready]]

Comment: You did not remove the master taint from your node, can you try `kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-` and then redoing `kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.taints}"`?

Comment: I do it but nothing change

Comment: Really? What did `kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master` say?

Comment: error: at least one taint update is required

Comment: My mistake, it should have been `kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-` with a `-` in the end.

Comment: node/ubuntu untainted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199804/discussion-between-alassane-ndiaye-and-yasin-lachini).

Answer (score 1):

I assume per given data outputs that the problem comes from [Kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) node agent, since `kubelet` primarily demands on [*CNI network plugin*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins) installation. In order to automatically configure networking features for the Pods, `kubelet` starts each time *CNI addon* in prior Pod creation to set up  pod’s network interface as well. Furthermore, [*CoreDNS*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/) discovery service relies on overlay container network to be reachable for all cluster nodes.

Although you've used [Flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel) CNI provider, `flannel` Pod is up and running, since `kubelet` can't create container interface for the particular `CoreDNS` Pods with lack of CNI configuration, I would recommend to reset `kubeadm` cluster with purging redundant component folder structure:

`$ sudo kubeadm reset`

`$ sudo systemctl stop docker && sudo systemctl stop kubelet`

`$ sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/`

`$ sudo rm -rf .kube/`

`$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/`

`$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cni/`

`$ sudo rm -rf /etc/cni/`

`$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/etcd/`

Bootstrap K8s cluster via `kubeadm`:

`$ sudo systemctl start docker && sudo systemctl start kubelet`

`$ sudo kubeadm init ...`

Further remove `node-role.kubernetes.io/master` taint and apply Flannel addon:

`$ kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`

`$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`

You might find also some useful information about `kubeadm` [*troubleshooting*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/) guide steps in the official K8s documentation.

Comment: I solve it .it is flannel error and by correct the version every thing is fine